# Is there a way to automatically upload the excel file in R

Tags: shiny

Is there a way to automatically upload the excel file.
Right now, the user has to manually upload the excel file(file.xlsx) that is kept under project folder.

Now the expected output is the moment the user clicks on "Automatically Upload the exceil file", the file should get uploaded.

Is there a way to achieve this? Let me know if this makes sense

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

ui <-
  dashboardPage(
    skin = "green",
    dashboardHeader(
      title      = "Test",
      titleWidth = 280
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(
      width = 280,
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem(text = "File(s) Upload", tabName = "Files",     icon = icon("file-upload")),
        menuItem(text = "Output", tabName = "Out1",     icon = icon("file-upload"))
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(
          tabName = "Files",
          fluidRow(
            column(
              width = 4,
              inputPanel(
                fileInput(inputId = "File1", label = "File", multiple = TRUE, accept = c(".xlsx")),
                selectInput(inputId = "Sheet1", label = "Select sheet", choices = NULL, selected = NULL),
                actionButton("sub", "Automatically Upload the exceil file")
              )
            )
          )
        ),
        tabItem(
          tabName = "Out1",
          fluidRow(column(width = 10, strong("Data")), align = "center"),
          br(),
          fluidRow(dataTableOutput("Data1"))
        )
      )
    )
  )


server <- function(input, output){
  
  
  # Populate the drop down menu with the names of the different Excel Sheets, but
  # only after a new file is supplied
  observe({
    
    sheet_names <- readxl::excel_sheets(input$File1$datapath)
    
    shiny::updateSelectInput(
      inputId = "Sheet1",
      choices = sheet_names,
      selected = sheet_names[[1]]
    )
    
  }) %>%
    bindEvent(input$File1)
  
  
  # When the drop down meny is populated, read the selected sheet from the Excel
  # file
  thedata <- reactive({
    
    req(input$Sheet1)
    
    readxl::read_xlsx(input$File1$datapath, sheet = input$Sheet1)
    
  })
  
  
  output$Data1 <-
    renderDataTable(
      thedata()
      , extensions = "Buttons"
      , options = list(
        dom = "Bfrtip"
        , buttons = c("copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print")
      )
    )
  
  # observe({
  #   print(reactiveValuesToList(input, all.names = FALSE))
  # })
}

runApp(
  list(ui = ui, server = server)
  , launch.browser = TRUE
)
```

Comment: Where is the file located? If it's on the user's local computer then, no. It would be a huge security risk if a web app could just automatically get a file from someone's computer. If it's in a networked location (e.g. SharePoint site, S3, network drive), then yes but it depends on where/how it's being stored.

Comment: the file is in the R project folder.

Comment: Are users running the Shiny app locally on their computer or is this on a server (e.g. RStudio Connection, shinyapps.io, Shiny Server)?

Comment: For now I’m using it locally. But I’ll be deploying on RS connect server